# Paginate Custom Post Type Page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I created a page for my custom post types.  The code can be viewed on Snippi: http://snippi.com/s/e8852rx

I'm trying to insert paginate_links, but for whatever reason it's simply not showing up.  Here is the paginate_links code (this code works on normal archive.php files):

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an archive page for your custom post-type?

Comment: You defining a new `WP_Query` object, but referencing the main `WP_Query` object in your call to paginate links. Change `$wp_query->max_num_pages` to `$loop->max_num_pages` and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't work. :-(

Comment: In `format` in the `paginate_links` call, try changing `paged` to `page`

Comment: That isn't doing the trick either.

Comment: Which part of it doesn't work? Do the page links show, but not work when you click on them, or does the pagination not show at all?

Comment: Does not show at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me (I've removed all the formating / custom post meta).

I would add, its not clear why you need to use a page with a custom template, and don't instead create a template called `archive-portfolio.php` which is used for a custom post type's archive pages (see [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy))

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
<div id="portfolio_content">
<div id="portfolio_wrap">

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => get_option('to_count_portfolio'), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
); ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span></br>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  

<?php

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
) );
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the "$loop->have_posts()" approach, like Stephen Harris pointed, you can also try looping the posts like this:

```
<?php foreach ($loop->get_posts() as $post) { ?>
     <span class="title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></span></br>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the portfolio post type root archive page?

If you move most of your code into an archive-portfolio.php file, then the loop should be setup correctly and paging should work out of the box, with no funky functions, or hacks or kludges, just like it does on post archives.

It also means you don't need to use you're own custom query, just use the main loop instead,  making the page load faster

Comment: Totally. And if the custom post type is set up properly the archive page will take the post type slug without extra dicking-around: eg, www.mysite/portfolio

Comment: When I change it to archive-portfolio.php, the original paginate_links code does not work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: is the call inside ro outside the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are refernecing the main query, so it's likely that it's trying to show 'posts' only, as opposed to your custom post type.

Not sure what your exact format is, but I'd redo the query so -

```
$args = Array( // Array of arguments for query_posts()
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => array('your-post-type-slug', 'another-post-type-slug-if-you-want')
);
query_posts($args);
```

This means that your code would become -

```
<?php
global $wp_query; // You don't need this if you are not in a function, so can probably be removed.

$args = Array( // Array of arguments for query_posts()
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => array('your-post-type-slug', 'another-post-type-slug-if-you-want')
);
query_posts($args);


$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I have struggled with on plenty of occasions.

Here's what has worked for me in this situation (WP 3.1.1):

```
<?php   
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged);
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($loop->have_posts()):
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                        //whatever output you require, such as, e.g:
                        the_excerpt();
                    endwhile;
                endif;
        ?>
```

Then, for the pagination controls:

```
<?php 
    echo custom_paginate_links( 
                            array(
                                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                                'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
                                ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a function within your functions.php file that handles pagination and can be used throughout your theme, for standard, and custom post types.

With the following function dropping `get_pagination()` into your theme will give you navigation where-ever you need it. I wrote a blog post on it here: http://deadlyhifi.com/2011/06/non-bloated-pagination-for-your-wordpress-functions-php-file/ (and the code is based on http://robertbasic.com/blog/wordpress-paging-navigation/ originally)

```
/**
 * A pagination function
 * @param integer $range: The range of the slider, works best with even numbers
 * Used WP functions:
 * get_pagenum_link($i) - creates the link, e.g. http://site.com/page/4
 * previous_posts_link(' ‚ '); - returns the Previous page link
 * next_posts_link(' é '); - returns the Next page link
 * http://robertbasic.com/blog/wordpress-paging-navigation/
 * tweaked by tdB ...
 */
function get_pagination($range = 4) {
global $paged, $wp_query;

// How much pages do we have?
if ( !$max_page ) {
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
}

// We need the pagination only if there is more than 1 page
if ( $max_page > 1 ) {
    if ( !$paged ) $paged = 1;

    echo '<div class="postpagination">';

    // To the previous page
    previous_posts_link('Prev');

    if ( $paged >= $range ) echo '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link(1) . '">1</a>';
    if ( $paged >= ($range + 1) ) echo '<span class="page-numbers">&hellip;</span>';

    // We need the sliding effect only if there are more pages than is the sliding range
    if ( $max_page > $range ) {
        // When closer to the beginning
        if ( $paged < $range ) {
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= ($range + 1); $i++ ) {
                    echo ( $i != $paged ) ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) .'">'.$i.'</a>' : '<span class="this-page">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
        // When closer to the end
        } elseif ( $paged >= ($max_page - ceil(($range/2))) ) {
            for ( $i = $max_page - $range; $i <= $max_page; $i++ ) {
                echo ( $i != $paged ) ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) .'">'.$i.'</a>' : '<span class="this-page">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
        // Somewhere in the middle
        } elseif ( $paged >= $range && $paged < ($max_page - ceil(($range/2))) ) {
            for ( $i = ($paged - ceil($range/2)); $i <= ($paged + ceil(($range/2))); $i++ ) {
                echo ($i != $paged) ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) .'">'.$i.'</a>' : '<span class="this-page">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
        }
    // Less pages than the range, no sliding effect needed
    } else {
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $max_page; $i++ ) {
                echo ($i != $paged) ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) .'">'.$i.'</a>' : '<span class="this-page">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
    }

    // On the last page, don't put the Last page link
    if ( $paged <= $max_page - ($range - 1) ) echo '<span class="page-numbers">&hellip;</span><a href="' . get_pagenum_link($max_page) . '">' . $max_page . '</a>';

    // Next page
    next_posts_link('Next');

    echo '</div><!-- postpagination -->';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I previously had something similar implemented... however, I am trying to achieve the same results with the built-in paginate function.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem using pagination on a custom **archive**. 
So, instead of making a page and then writing my own query on it, just copy/paste `archive.php` and rename it match your custom post, eg `archive-videos.php`.

If you really want to use custom page template, add this just before your query:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'paged' => get_query_var('page') ) )
```

More info: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html